# Работа с камерой в Android

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Для камеры есть коллбеки задания превью, получения картинки, но не понятно одно: у меня есть изображение в камере — делаю тач по какой-либо области — нужно получить область тача (цвет или хотя бы байты с данными).
Каким образом?

**UPD**:
Возникла проблема с получением картинки с канваса.
Делаем так:

```
Canvas canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas(mHolder.getSurfaceFrame());
```

А что дальше - непонятно.

Про канву можно забыть. Массив с изображением мы получаем из коллбека превьюшки для камеры, но получаем всегда `null` и нагугливаем [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893072/getting-frames-from-video-image-in-android).

Использую метод так:

```
Camera.Size camSize = camera.getParameters().getPictureSize();
int[] outBuff = new int[camSize.width * camSize.height];
decodeYUV(outBuff, data, camSize.width, camSize.height);
Log.d(TAG, "int[]=" + Arrays.toString(outBuff));
```

В лог ничего не выводится.

**Итого:**
Нужно по тачу в превью камеры получить область изображения (в байтах). То есть, делаем тач — получаем кусок картинки на которой был сделан тач.

Comment: так и делаю уже, но как-то пока не пойму как получить с канвы изображение

Comment: Наверно надо не с канваса брать пиксели а из колбеков.

Comment: так и делаю, теперь проблема такая - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893072/getting-frames-from-video-image-in-android

Comment: @DroidAlex, если не трудно, перед тем как закрывать проблему как неактуальную, чирканите в 2х словах ответ, как вы ее решили или ссылочку которая вам помогла. Всем будет полезнее. А то уже пачка вопросов весит закрытые и без ответов.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, какую конкретно область вы хотите получить? Какого она должны быть размера? Тап происходит на 1 пиксель, а у Вас написано, будто Вы хотите брать большую область.

Comment: @Daniel Shatz про 1 пиксель откуда такие сведения?

Comment: @DroidAlex https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать `YuvImage`:

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) { 
  Camera.Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
  YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, previewSize.width, previewSize.height, null);
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
  yuvImage.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, baos);
  byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

  // дальше можно получить область касания
  someImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,
    tapRegionX,
    tapRegionY,
    tapRegionWidth,
    tapRegionHeight));
}
```